# Output csv file from database table

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to output table data in csv file.

```
$query = new QUERY();
$clause = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE company_id='$company_id'
           INTO OUTFILE 'file_name.csv'
           FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '\"'
           LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";
$query->run($clause);
```

**ERROR:**

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000]:
Invalid authorization specification: 1045 Access denied for user
'my_username'@'%' (using password: YES)' in
D:\home\site\wwwroot\application\libraries\query.php:426
```

What's wrong in this? How can I import data in csv file and place it on server?

**EDIT:**

```
Stack trace:
#0 D:\home\site\wwwroot\application\libraries\query.php(426): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 D:\home\site\wwwroot\application\libraries\query.php(470): QUERY->RUN_QUERY('SELECT * FROM a...', Array)
#2 D:\home\site\wwwroot\application\controllers\manage_clients.php(116): QUERY->run('SELECT * FROM a...')
#3 [internal function]: Manage_clients->delete_company()
#4 D:\home\site\wwwroot\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 D:\home\site\wwwroot\index.php(203): require_once('D:\\home\\site\\ww...')
#6 {main}
```

Comment: The error tells you what's wrong. The user was denied. Do you have the right username and password? Does that user have the right permissions on that database?

Comment: No one can give you an accurate answer until you tell us which line is 426.

Comment: You didn't even include any of the code from the script that's actually throwing the error

Comment: @Adelphia: This is internal query class file. You can see stack trace that I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously,

```
Invalid authorization, Access denied for user 'my_username'@'%'
```

So check your credentials, i.e. if your usernam and pwd match, and if both are accepted from the IP you use.

EDIT: If all other queries run fine, maybe they come in from another source, like another server? One thing that springs to my mind is that you might have no permission to write the outfile itself - but I wonder if there would be another error message for that. Maybe your user has no right to use the OUTFILE command?

Comment: all other queries are running fine with this username and password.

Comment: I am running these query on same server. And I can store images on server without any problem. I think it's something with the query.

Comment: You can store files, but can your mysql user store that specific file to the specific destination?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your user has the right privileges. Run these queries to set up the privileges and then the 2nd query to grant file on the user. Granting all privileges doesn't give file, so you need to do that separately.

```
grant all privileges on your_database.*  to 'asdfsdf'@'localhost'  identified by 'your_password';
flush privileges;
grant file on *.* to 'asdfsdf'@'localhost';
```

You can run `show grants;` to see what has been granted to users.

Another way to do it would be:

```
service mysql restart --skip-networking --skip-grant-tables
mysql <enter>
update mysql.user set File_priv = 'Y' where user='gs' and host='localhost';
exit
service mysql restart
```